# How to get real lines count of CEdit control

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to add verticall scrollbar to my `CEdit`-inherited control which should appear only if it's needed. The obvious startegy I'm using is to determine whether text height is larger than control's height. I've found few examples of such a task [here](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/multiline-edit-box-with-automatic-scroll-bar-display/) and in SO post [Any way to retrieve text height, in pixels, of text within a `CEditBox`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810172/any-way-to-retrieve-text-height-in-pixels-of-text-within-a-ceditbox). In both examples the height of text is determined as `linesCount * lineHeight`. However I has a text that doesn't contain line breaks, for example:

```
CString text = L"Hello Hello Hello /*few more times*/ Hello Hello Hello";
```

In that case `CEdit::GetLinesCount` method always returns `1` despite it has an `ES_MULTILINE` style option (and horizontal scrollbar is off). So, how can I find whether I need vertical scrollbar or not?

Comment: [`DrawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) might be able to do the calculation you're looking for when using the `DT_CALCRECT` (and possibly `DT_EDITCONTROL`) formatting flags.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? That is, what are you going to do if you know that you need a vertical scroll-bar? Resize the control, change its style, or what else? The `GetLinesCount()` method returns the number of lines of the text currently in the control, not the lines its visible area __can display__ without a scroll-bar.

Comment: I'm trying to hide the scrollbar if it doesn't needed, and show it when needed, for example, when text gets out of the control's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

With the hint of IInspectable I ended up using the `DrawText` method, however at least my variant is not precise - it gives bigger height than actually needed:

```
void ScrollEdit::CheckVerticalScrolling()
{
    CString text;
    GetWindowText(text);

    CClientDC dc { this };
    CRect     rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int r =
        DrawText(dc.GetSafeHdc(), text, text.GetLength(), &rect, DT_CALCRECT | DT_EDITCONTROL | DT_WORDBREAK);
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    ShowVertScrollBar(r > rect.Height());
}
```

Comment: Remember to ensure that you are using the *edit controls* font. You might need to get it from the edit control, set it in the DC, do your calcs, and restore the original font in the DC afterwards.